# How to specify type constraints in a datatype in Standard-ML?

Tags: functional-programming, sml

Consider this datatype in Standard-ML:

```
datatype 't options = Null
                   | Some of 't
```

And I also have this other datatype:

```
datatype option = Apple | Orange | Melon
```

I would like to specify that `datatype options` should only accept `datatype option` as its input type `'t`. How to do this?

Comment: Why not just remove `'t` and write `datatype options = Null | Some of option`?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov: I knew I was overdoing things. Very new to SML eheh. Thanks a lot, really valuable!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no such feature in SML, nor as an extension of any SML dialect that I've heard of.

You can define a more specialized version as a type alias:

```
type option_options = option options
```

And you can make that type abstract in the module's signature if you want, but that will hide the constructors.

Comment: I suppose the closest thing is a refinement type in [F*](https://www.fstar-lang.org/).

Answer (score 0):

How about this, with self made option:

```
strobel@suse132-intel:~> sml
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.79 [built: Tue Dec 22 21:53:32 2015]
- datatype fruits = Apple | Orange | Melon;
datatype fruits = Apple | Melon | Orange
- datatype fruitopt = Nofruit | Fruit of fruits;
datatype fruitopt = Fruit of fruits | Nofruit
-
```